# circle navigation animation with css?

Tags: css, menu, html-lists

I am trying to make circle navigation animated with CSS, but the problem is that when the mouse hovers over one of the menu links, all the menus use the effect that I wanted to be only on the selected link. Is there is any way to do this?

here is the link for my result: http://jsfiddle.net/amromar/Fgnmw/

CSS:

```
#nav li {
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
display:table-cell;
ul.box li {  
    display: block;
    width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:1000px;font-size:20px;color:#fff;line-height:100px;text-align:center;background:#000; 

}
ul.box li{ -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease; 
    overflow: hidden; }  

ul.box:hover li{  
display: block;
      width:200px;height:200px;border-radius:1000px;font-size:30px;color:#fff;line-height:100px;text-align:center;background:#333;
      overflow: hidden;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="box" id="nav" >
<li >home</li>
<li><a href="#">about</a></li>
<li>our tour</li>
<li>contact</li>
<li>hellow</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you recreate your menu on jsfiddle.net for us to examine?

Comment: yeah its here http://jsfiddle.net/amromar/Fgnmw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought (and had posted then deleted) that you just needed to change the `:hover` to the `li` element, so this selector `ul.box:hover li` to this `ul.box li:hover`. But that was only part of the solution, because the sizing problem was your `display: table-cell` on the `li` elements, which was forcing them to expand to the height of the wrapper. I believe I have come up with an acceptable solution to get what you seem to want to achieve (has similar effects as the `display: table-cell` only without the height issue).

### [Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgnmw/19/)

**CSS**

```
#nav { 
   max-width: 500px; /* this keeps your five circles no more than 100px wide */
   margin: 20px auto; /* only needed if you are centering the nav */
   /* optional; you may want to clear the floats or give the nav a "float" to wrap
      the nav around the floated children inside. Whether you need to do this or 
      not depends on your application*/
}

#nav li {
   list-style:none;
   list-style-type:none;
   display:block;
   float: left;
}

ul.box li{  
    width:20%; /* Using the wrapper to set the width, 100px will be max without animation */
    height:100px; /* Keep the height fixed, even if narrow width "squeezes" the circle */
    border-radius:50px; /* half the max-width is all you need */
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000;     
}

ul.box li { /* no changes here */
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}  

ul.box:hover li {
    /* cause the other li's to "shrink" to 
       accomodate the larger size of the one being hovered */
    width: 15%; 
}

ul.box li:hover {  
      width:40%; /* animate to twice the size for the one being hovered */
      height: 200px; /* make twice the fixed height */
      border-radius:100px;
      font-size:30px;
      color:#fff;
      line-height: 200px;
      text-align:center;
      background:#333;  
}
```

Comment: tht's amazing scotts its what im looking for thank you so much all of you thanks omega for your help

Answer (score 0):

They were all showing the effect the effect was being applied to all the items with this selector: `ul.box:hover li`

Instead, I've given each item a class, and set the selector to `.item:hover`

HTML:

```
<ul class="box boxr" id="nav" >
<li class="item">home</li>
<li class="item"><a href="#">about</a></li>
<li class="item">our tour</li>
<li class="item">contact</li>
<li class="item">hellow</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#nav li{list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
display:table-cell;

}
.nav ul{margin:20px;}

ul.box li{  
display: block;
    width:100px;height:100px;border-radius:1000px;font-size:20px;color:#fff;line-height:100px;text-align:center;background:#000; 

}
ul.box li{ -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -o-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;  
    transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease; 
    overflow: hidden; }  

.item:hover
{  
display: block;
      width:200px;height:200px;border-radius:1000px;font-size:30px;color:#fff;line-height:100px;text-align:center;background:#333;
      overflow: hidden;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fgnmw/7/

Comment: that's great thanks so much but still effect the height of the other circles when mouse hover on items?? any solution for that

Comment: That is because you've got all of the li's contained in display:table. This means when even the hover occurs, the effected li will increase the height of the "table" to 200px, and all the other li's are simply filling the space that's created. Change display:table; to display:inline-block to stop this. But then some li's may start a new line when a hover occurs. See it here http://jsfiddle.net/Fgnmw/17/